# How can I map semicolon-separated PathParams in Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Is there a way to use this parameter style:

> /products/123;456;789

in JAX-RS with Jersey? If I use PathParam, only the first parameter in the list is returned. I tried to escape the semicolon but then Jersey returns only "123;456;789" as the value of the first parameter list entry

I declared the GET method as

```
public List<Product> getClichedMessage(@PathParam("ids") List<String> idList)
```

Update: I am referring to the [Jersey user guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/1.1.5/user-guide.html#d4e226) for Jersey 1.1.5:

> In general the Java type of the method
>   parameter may (...) 4) be List,
>   Set or SortedSet, where T
>   satisfies 2 or 3 above. The resulting
>   collection is read-only. (...)
>   Sometimes parameters may contain more
>   than one value for the same name. If
>   this is the case then types in 4) may
>   be used to obtain all values.

Update: here is my test code:

```
package de.betabeans.resources;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{ids}")
    @Produces({"text/plain"})
    public String getClichedMessage(@PathParam("ids") List<String> idList) {
        return "size=" + idList.size();
    }

}
```

Test URL with semicolon escaped: http://localhost:8080/resources/test/1%3B2%3B3

Update: the [changelog for Jersey 1.3](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/tags/jersey-1.3/jersey/changes.txt) include this information:

> Fixed issue 540
>   http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-540
>   Parameterized types of
>   List/Set/SortedSet are supported for
>   parameters,   for example
>   @QueryParam("d") List>,
>   if there is a   StringReaderProvider
>   registered that supports the type
>   List.

I'll check out StringReaderProvider based on this post http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jersey.user/7545

Comment: About the second update: Sorry, but you are not going to succeed this way. You continue to use matrix parameters, while you think that the semicolon is a separator for path parameters. It is not. And it's not going to become one. It's separator for matrix parameters, to create urls like /moremaps.com/map/color;lat=50;long=20;scale=32000

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you use semicolon, you create [Matrix parameters](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html).
You can use either `@MatrixParam` or `PathSegment` to get them. Example:

```
 public String get(@PathParam("param") PathSegment pathSegment)
```

Pay attention that Matrix parameters are these that follow the original parameter.
So in case of "123;456;789" - 123 is path parameter, while 456 and 789 are the names of matrix parameters.

So if you want to get products by ids, you can do something like this:

```
public List<Product> getClichedMessage(@PathParam("ids") PathSegment pathSegment) {
    Set<String> ids = pathSegment.getMatrixParameters().keySet();
    // continue coding
}
```

Pay attention that your url should be `/products/ids;123;456;789`

Actually, IMO it is not a very good design: you use matrix parameter name as a value. I think using query parameters is better: `/products?id=123&id=456&id=789`, so you can easily get them in method:

```
public List<Product> getClichedMessage(@QueryParam("id") List<String> ids)
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! See my update, in the documentation it seems like PathParam actually supports multiple values too.

Comment: Well, it's partially true. You can write something like @Path("/url/{param}/and/{param}) so @PathParam will be duplicated and it can be received as a list. But I don't think its what you want.

Comment: Yes this works, but then the number of parameters in the URL must match exactly the number in the pattern. My workaround was is to use String instead of List<String> and do the parsing in code (String.split(ids)).

Comment: Well, it's obvious that your workaround will work. You get the whole path segment and parse it yourself. This way you can use anything as a separator and it will work. Just pay attention that it is not very RESTful, since you use predefined conventions in a bit different way then you supposed to use them.

Comment: Ok, I'll check out the /products?id=123&id=456&id=789 style then (didn't know parameters can appear multiple times). Actually the semicolon-separated parameter is used in the Stackoverflow API (see http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/users-by-ids)

Comment: Well, may be they don't know that semicolon is used in matrix URIs... :) My point was that if you decide to use a propriety separator, which is ok, don't use semicolon, since it's used for matrix parameters. Use something else.

Comment: Thanks @Tarlog I confirm that your suggestion works in restEasy also.