# URL is truncated after semicolon while requesting @pathParam In REST

Tags: java, rest, jersey

In javascript I am encoding the path and attaching to URL. In GET call REST URL is truncated after the semicolon.

> path name : !#;@$^&()_+{}:,.'[]
>
> encodeURI(path name) :
>   %21%23%3B%40%24%5E%26%28%29_%2B%7B%7D%3A%2C.%27%5B%5D
>
> URL+path :
>   ../reports/SMC-%21%23%3B%40%24%5E%26%28%29_%2B%7B%7D%3A%2C.%27%5B%5D/configs?_=1482329220060

```
@GET
    @Path("/{report_name}/configs")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @ApiOperation(value = "Fetches the configurations of the report",httpMethod = HttpMethod.GET, response = ReportConfigOptions.class)
    public Response getAllConfigOptions(@PathParam("report_name") String fqReportName,
            @QueryParam("context_parameters") ReportContextParameters contextParameters,
            @QueryParam("apply_locale") boolean applyLocale) {
@PathParam("report_name") String fqReportName 
....
```

*fqReportName* will be trancated after semicolon (;)
fqReportName : !#

is it possible to prevent this trancation?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that jersy is considering ; as Matrix parameter indication.
see this answer:
[How can I map semicolon-separated PathParams in Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503272/how-can-i-map-semicolon-separated-pathparams-in-jersey)

EDIT:

This has worked for me:

```
@GET
@Path("s/{s: .*}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response s(@PathParam("s") String s){
    return Response.ok(s).build();

}
```

You might need to refine your regex not to include "/" since you have a second path segment after the path param.

Comment: But I don't want semicolon separation, I want the path as it is in @pathParam.